# access of an array inside another array in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have two arrays defined like these

```
var theory= new Array();
var first;
var second;

function arrTheory () {
    this.first= first;
    this.second= second;
}

var subject= new Array();
...
function arrSubject () {
    ...
    this.theory= theory;
    ...
}
```

how can i access to the elements in the theory array inside the bigger one?
I've tried

```
subject[0].theory.first;
```

but it doesn't work while

```
subject[0].name;
```

which is another field of the big array works fine. what i've missed?

Comment: post complete code please.What is name here

Comment: read the last line of the question!

Comment: You have not pushed any values in the arrays..Can you please add complete code..

Comment: the arrays have elements pushed inside. the last line will never work without a push. I push first and second inside the theory array, and then I push everything inside the bigger one!

Comment: theory.first means that theory is an object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is, you have an array with element as "obj" and added to another array.
So to access to a you could try

> subject[0].theory[0].first;

I mean access to element of array by index and them access to the element of the object.

Comment: Ok, have you make a arr = new arrTheory and the push?

Comment: yes.. inside every subject I have only one theory pushed.. but i don't know how many subjects I have

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a good guess given the information you've provided.

`theory` in `subject[0].theory` is an array, right? How come you are using it like `subject[0].theory.first`? You should use an indexer like `subject[0].theory[0]`.

In the code you showed us (before any potential edits), you don't add anything to the `var theory= new Array();`

Also beware to make sure that `this` is what you really expect. In JavaScript, the context of this changes depending on context of the caller and that's confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
subject[0].theory[0].first;
```

try that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` in `arrTheory()` and `arrSubject()` will cause a syntax error because they are functions not objects and you need rather to set those properties to `theory` and `subject` arrays instead so you must use the correspondent array name instead of this like following:

```
var theory= new Array();
var first = "first";
var second = "second";

function arrTheory () {
    theory.first= first;
    theory.second= second;
}

var subject= new Array();
function arrSubject () {
    subject.theory= theory;
}
arrTheory();
arrSubject();

alert(subject.theory.first + " / " + subject.theory.second);
```

then you can access first and second properties like this:

```
subject.theory.first
subject.theory.second
```

in the code above property name is not set in subject, if it's already set in the original code you can call it like this:

```
subject.name
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/5JMxX/)